# PermissionError: [WinError 32] using pandas-dedupe

Tags: python, pandas, windows, duplicates, permissionerror

I am trying to use pandas-dedupe, but after labelling data I run into permission issues I cannot solve. Minimum working example:

```
import pandas_dedupe
import seaborn as sns

if __name__ == "__main__":
    iris = sns.load_dataset('iris')
    result = pandas_dedupe.dedupe_dataframe(iris, ["sepal_width", "sepal_length", "species"])
```

After labelling some data, the files `dedupe_dataframe_learned_settings` and `dedupe_dataframe_training.json` get created.
But during the deduplication process I run into errors like

```
PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'C:\\Users\\THOMAS~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmp_vrp9vbr'
```

I tried setting `n_cores=1` in the `dedupe_dataframe` method, but it didn't help me. What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem I solved it by disabling multiprocessing. You can disable multiprocessing by setting `n_cores=0` as shown below:

```
pandas_dedupe.dedupe_dataframe(df, ['first_name', 'last_name'], n_cores=0)
```

This should resolve the error.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems on Windows. I didn't find a solution for Windows itself, but using WSL(2) you can get this working properly.

Lyonk71 whom (co-)made the pandas-dedupe package also made an installation video, see below.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dq183fOB1Xg&t

Hope this helps you out, success!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).